Как изменить количество отображаемых строк на странице
Только осваиваю Flutter (и Dart вместе с ним).
Хочу вывести таблицу с тремя столбцами.
Не могу понять, как изменить количество отображаемых строк на странице (Rows per page).
Возможно, нужно как-то переписать onRowsPerPageChanged, но как это сделать - не знаю.
Весь код:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: PaginatedDataTableExample(),
    );
  }
}

class PaginatedDataTableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const PaginatedDataTableExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: PaginatedDataTable(
          columns: const [
            DataColumn(label: Text(
                'id',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
            ),),
            DataColumn(label: Text(
                'Начало',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
            ),),
            DataColumn(label: Text(
                'Конец',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
            ),),
          ],
          source: DataTableSourceExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DataTableSourceExample extends DataTableSource{
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = List.generate(
    201,
    (index) => {
      "id": index,
      "begin_datetime": DateTime.now(),
      "end_date": DateTime.now(),
    },
  );

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text(data[index]["id"].toString())),
      DataCell(Text(data[index]["begin_datetime"].toString())),
      DataCell(Text(data[index]["end_date"].toString())),
    ],);
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => data.length;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
  
}


Если я правильно понял вопрос, то нужно просто указать количество строк на странице в виджете таблицы:
...    
child: PaginatedDataTable(
   rowsPerPage:3,
   columns: const [
...



Немного не то. Нужно, чтобы можно было динамически изменять количество строк на странице (Rows per page): 10, 20, 50, 100.
